# Bash script, analyze log file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

If its possible to show this in not one line format, but bash script. Its easier to understand, and want to see how to manipulate with array and fields of records. No Perl, Python and so on.

I have log file `out.log` :

```
03:01:29.317    info    process 1   PC1
05:22:42.211    info    process 3   PC2
05:22:42.302    info    process 3   acknowledge
06:09:32.083    info    process 2   PC5
05:12:32.759    ERROR   process 1   acknowledge
07:21:45.112    info    process 22  PC16
08:12:32.300    info    process 19  PC1
09:25:41.000    info    process 19  acknowledge
06:09:35.083    info    process 2   acknowledge
03:01:25.714    info    process 14  PC1
05:12:32.308    info    process 14  acknowledge
05:12:32.309    ERROR   process 22  acknowledge
05:12:32.300    info    process 7   PC1
07:25:41.000    info    process 7   acknowledge
```

I want to find all entries about PC1, each record about PC1 has acknowledge record and acknowledge we can find by process number field, its the same for PC1 and acknowledge. By the way For the same PC1 process number is different.
step by step:

1. find all fields for PC1 and remember process number
2. go through the file again and find all entries with all process numbers which are connected to PC1
3. If status is ERROR print : 
   this record and record about PC1 which it belongs to. and sort them by time in pair

How can I manipulate with fields of result, for example compare time? Expected result:

```
03:01:29.317    info    process 1   PC1
05:12:32.759    ERROR   process 1   acknowledge
```

*here are all my tries and results, sorry for long text*

**CASE1**

```
a=($(awk '$5 == "PC1" { print}' out.log))
echo ${a[@]:0}

03:01:29.317 info process 1 PC1 08:12:32.300 info process 19 PC1 03:01:25.714 info process 14 PC1 05:12:32.300 info process 7 PC1
```

if i use echo ${a[index]i it prints out all records where were found PC1. but it looks like they are not array but string, because echo ${a[0] is first field 03:01:29.317 echo ${a[4] is PC1, and echo ${a[5]  08:12:32.300 which are connected with the next record

when i try to go through the loop

```
a=($(awk '$5 == "PC1" { print $4}' out.log))
for i in "${a[@]}"
do
    awk -v search="$i" '$0 ~ search { print}' out.log
```

done
it outputs all file without any searching

**case 2**

```
awk '$5=="PC1" { h[$4]; print; next } $4 in h { print; delete h[$4] }' out.log

03:01:29.317    info    process 1   PC1
05:12:32.759    ERROR   process 1   acknowledge
08:12:32.300    info    process 19  PC1
09:25:41.000    info    process 19  acknowledge
03:01:25.714    info    process 14  PC1
05:12:32.308    info    process 14  acknowledge
05:12:32.300    info    process 7   PC1
07:25:41.000    info    process 7   acknowledge
```

that its not bad, but know i dont know how to process it. I guess the way should be the same, but i dont know how to implement it. something like this
awk '$5=="PC1" { h[$4]; print; next } $4 in h { print; delete h[$4] }' out.log| awk '$2 == "ERROR" { h[$4]; print; next } $4 in h { print; delete h[$4] }' out.log
gives

```
05:12:32.759    ERROR   process 1   acknowledge
05:12:32.309    ERROR   process 22  acknowledge
```

all errors messages but no related process message

**case 3 by schorsch312**

```
grep -w "PC1" out.log | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -i grep -w "process {}" out.log
```

output is:

```
03:01:29.317    info    process 1   PC1
05:12:32.759    ERROR   process 1   acknowledge
08:12:32.300    info    process 19  PC1
09:25:41.000    info    process 19  acknowledge
03:01:25.714    info    process 14  PC1
05:12:32.308    info    process 14  acknowledge
05:12:32.300    info    process 7   PC1
07:25:41.000    info    process 7   acknowledge
```

its also great.
and the extended string

```
grep -w "PC1" out.log | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -i grep -w "process {}" out.log |grep -w "ERROR"| awk '{print $4}' |xargs -i grep -w "process {}" out.log
```

gives result as needed

```
03:01:29.317    info    process 1   PC1
05:12:32.759    ERROR   process 1   acknowledge
```

but i dont like how does it look

and i still dont have any simple bash script, but i  believe its easy :(

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: a=($(awk  '{if ($5 == "PC1") {print $4}}' out.log
for i in "${a[@]}"
do
 :
grep -w $i server.log
done

Comment: @Inian 'a=($(awk  '{if ($5 == "PC1") {print $4}}' out.log
for i in "${a[@]}"
do
 :
grep -w $i server.log
done' i can't to make up how to do this , :( i understand how to awk for certain field, also i understand that  result of awk i have to pass as array to bash, after that for each element of array (in our example its process number) i should grep one more time all out.log, during greping i have to check $3 == "ERROR" if error for the same id i have to find pair. So i asked how to operate in bash with all this:(

Comment: why `process 19` presented with 2 entries in your output while the condition *If status is ERROR* was not met?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question; as written, it is a request for free work. However it looks like you have made an effort since, and you've written some code and pasted it in the comments. Would you merge that into your question, by editing it? That would make the start of a good question. Please also show what problem you are having with your code.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, u'r right, its my fault, i just wished to show that it should be done step by step because of dependencies :(

Comment: @halfer i ve added my tries, please dont close this, i really need help. All tutorials are very basic about just how to find something, but i have no meet cases like this..also i looked to for loops in bash but i can't operate with fields...or i do need entire awk statement in the if condition for for loop?

Comment: OK, that's a bit better. Can you indicate, [by editing the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44494454/edit), what your code does currently? "I've tried this" still does not explain **the problem you actually have**.

Comment: @halfer, i got the way you think..its great approach, and ill do my best to solve my problem with your help in half an hour ill show it

Comment: @halfer, its me again , i expanded description. :)

Comment: @Inian i described all my steps, and ways

Comment: OK, thanks. Posting tips: use capital letters at the start of sentences, and for the personal pronoun "I" (I've fixed this before in your post, I'm not editing it again). When you have code like this `awk '$5=="PC1" { h[$4]; print; next } $4 in h { print; delete h[$4] }' out.log| awk '$2 == "ERROR" { h[$4]; print; next } $4 in h { print; delete h[$4] }'`, put it in backticks, otherwise it is unreadable in paragraph text. Try not to use sad face emoticons in your text. People are not more likely to help you if you "look sad"! Good luck with your question.

Comment: @halfer, Ok, I'll do my best to follow the rules

Comment: you said *gives result as needed* and *but i dont like how does it look* . And how should it look?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i would like to have something like : awk for search pattern and array pass to bash, where through the loop can do everything with it, like case 1, but i can not do this, and no help is :) schorsch312's answer is cool, but a little bit confusing because of repeating almost the same string twice :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following

```
 grep -w "PC1" st1 | awk '{print $4}' | xargs -i grep -w "process {}" st1
```

1.) You grep after PC1
2.) From that grep you get the process number using awk
3.) You grep after this process number, xargs puts the process number at the right place

You can than handle the error case in the same manner.

Comment: your answer works! thanks for it, but looks a bit strange :) is it way to make it look good ?))

Comment: You can combine the first grep and awk 
    awk '{ if ($5=="PC1") print $4 }' | xargs -i grep -w "process {}" st1